# get a value of a suggested action in botframework

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, botframework

how to access the value clikced by user while using suggested actions in botframework

```
// Create the activity and add suggested actions.
   var activity = MessageFactory.SuggestedActions(
       new CardAction[]
       {
           new CardAction(title: "red", type: ActionTypes.ImBack, value: "red"),
           new CardAction( title: "green", type: ActionTypes.ImBack, value: "green"),
           new CardAction(title: "blue", type: ActionTypes.ImBack, value: "blue")
       }, text: "Choose a color");

   // Send the activity as a reply to the user.
   await context.SendActivity(activity);
```

Answer (score 1):

As demonstrated by this sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/08.suggested-actions/SuggestedActionsBot.cs#L69  The **context.Activity.Text** property of the user's response will contain the user's choice.

```
string userChoice = turnContext.Activity.Text;
```